# Evolution keeps disappearing?

Tags: debian, logs, evolution

I am running Debian 6.0.3 (squeeze) and Evolution 2.30.3. I keep noticing that evolution disappears (gmail account). It never throws up a crash dialog. What is going on? How can I tell what is happening?

Comment: I am running the amd64 version.

Answer (score 2):

Run it from the command line:

```
$ evolution
```

If it is crashing, you'll see a bunch of error messages on the terminal window and hopefully find clues as to how to fix it.

Comment: `ronaldo@debian:~$ evolution --debug=evo.log`
`Segmentation fault`
The **evo.log** file shows no errors.

Comment: @RonaldoNascimento: There you go, `Segmentaion fault` is basically a bug in `evolution`. It's attempting to access memory it shouldn't be accessing. See if there's an update for evolution. It may also be a bug in one of the libraries used by evolution.

Comment: nm switched back to mutt